# regex pattern replace from coma to dollar($) in php

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem with regex, i did effort with this code "

```
$pattern ='(\"[,]\")';
$replacement = '$';
$string='array("FORM", "481072307", "481072307"),array("pattern_x", "3,1,1990","02,121"),array("pattern_y", "f,g,j","1,36"),array("STARTDATE", "08/07/2014","07/11/2014")';
$output = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
```

this is the output :

```
array("FORM", "481072307", "481072307"),array("pattern_x", "3,1,1990$02,121"),array("pattern_y","f,g,j$1,36"),array("STARTDATE", 08/07/2014","07/11/2014")
```

but it was not  i expected, but this :

```
array("FORM", "481072307", "481072307"),array("pattern_x", "3,1,1990'$'02,121"),array("pattern_y","f,g,j'$'1,36"),array("STARTDATE", /07/2014","07/11/2014");
```

hope anybody help true regex with my case. Thanks.

Comment: Why not str_replace of single quote?

Comment: `$pattern = '","'` and `$replacement = "'$'";`. You don't need `preg_replace` at all, `str_replace` is totally sufficient for this. Also, to understand regular expressions better, visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`$replacement = "'$'";`